# Using a For Loop to work with many variables where the names differ only slightly (different numbers)

Tags: java, jtogglebutton

I have a program where I am using several hundred JToggleButtons. Their names differ only slightly by numbers (e.g. jToggleButton1, jToggleButton2, jToggleButton3,...)
Is there a way that I can use a for loop when doing the same thing to multiple buttons? 
For instance, if I want to programmatically change the states of several buttons, could I loop through them, changing the ending number of the name each time?

Comment: Are you trying to create "dynamic variable names"?

Comment: I don't know honestly. I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to put them all in an array or `ArrayList` and use a `foreach` loop.

```
ArrayList<JToggleButton> toggleButtonArrayList = new ArrayList<JToggleButton>();
// ... insert your JToggleButtons to the ArrayList here...

for (JToggleButton myButton : toggleButtonArrayList) {
    myButton.changeSomething();
    // ...  do whatever you want here ...
}
```

Comment: How would an array be set up in this situation? I think I will be using an array instead of an array list.

Comment: Nvm. I see that it would be   'JToggleButton m_jTogBtn[][] = new JToggleButton[20][20];'

Comment: Where the comment in your code says to insert JToggleButtons to the ArrayList, how do I go about that? Is there a general way or do I have to go through all 400 buttons sending them each to a specific slot in my array?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this by putting all the buttons into an array, or an `ArrayList`.